# How to control simulation step size from API

Tags: simulation, gazebo

I can control the length of a Gazebo step size through the world's SDF. Example with `max_step_size`=4 ms :

```xml
<physics name="4ms" type="ode">
            <max_step_size>0.004</max_step_size>
            <real_time_factor>-1.0</real_time_factor>
            <real_time_update_rate>250</real_time_update_rate>
</physics>
```

**But, can I also set this value through an API call ?**

Another simulation parameter, the Update rate, can be controlled through the .SDF **or** programmatically with a call to `gz::sim::ServerConfig::SetUpdateRate`. Example:

```cpp
// Object to pass custom configuration to the server
gz::sim::ServerConfig serverConfig;

// Populate with some configuration, for example, the SDF file to load
serverConfig.SetSdfFile(config["world_sdf_path"].as<std::string>());
serverConfig.SetUpdateRate(update_rate); // in Hz
```

I would like to do the same for `max_step_size`.

Note 1: Gazebo's `SimulationRunner` seem to have this capability (see [this method](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/001dd9b829eb8e8b4465d87c6c70ccf4ee2e6b6a/src/SimulationRunner.cc#L1362-L1366)), but I don't know how to access it from a "user" point of view.

Note 2: Transfer from [unanswered answers.gazebosim question](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28911/how-to-control-simulation-speed-from-api/)

Comment: Can you give more background info why you want to do this? I.e. what you want to achieve by changing this programmatically?

Comment: I do co-simulation with another simulator (namely ns-3, a network simulator), so I need to control the execution steps of Gazebo finely. I chose to keep a fixed step_size during the whole simulation. The user edit a global configuration file and has the ability to define `max_step_size`. For now, I have to inject the user choice in the .sdf file, but this is ugly XML editing, which is less elegant than an API call.

The way `REAL_TIME_update_rate` can be changed is way more convenient and readable, but clearly this is just for comfort as it still can be done with xml editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set_physics` service is able to set the `max_step_size` using a `gz::msgs::Physics`. I don't see a tutorial for this, but some code from the user_commands integration test can be used as a reference:

- https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/gz-sim7/test/integration/user_commands.cc#L1081-L1103

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for the pointer !